# Hiding scrollbar and making custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I wanted to make a page like https://www.guillaumetomasi.com/ .How can I hide the scrollbar and make a custom one like that in the page.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS attributes like `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow-y: hidden` you can hide scrollbars.

The custom scrollbar and the scrolling proccess is controlled by Javascript via and events.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is simple and that's, they are not using any scrolling at all, but what you feel is a modified scroll for those slides is actually a slideshow built by JavaScript functionalities. These side slideshow are nowadays in trend and gives you a feel of pseudo scroll. It will be better if you would ask how to achieve that slideshow in a web page instead of that scrolling...

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar can be hidden with css `::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0px;}`
The custom scroll bar is made with javascript. Here's an example of how it could be done:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var section1 = document.getElementById("section1");
  var section2 = document.getElementById("section2");
  var section3 = document.getElementById("section3");
  
  var indicator = document.getElementById("scroll-indicator");
  if (window.scrollY < section2.offsetTop ) { // If scroll height is above section 2
      indicator.innerText = "1"
  }
  if (window.scrollY > (section1.offsetTop + section1.offsetHeight)) { // If scrolled past section 1
      indicator.innerText = "2"
  }
  if (window.scrollY > (section2.offsetTop + section2.offsetHeight)) {// If scrolled past section 2
      indicator.innerText = "3"
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: arial;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; /*This removes the scroll bar*/
}
```

```html
<div id="section1" style="height: 500px; background-color: lightblue">Scroll Down</div>
<div id="section2" style="height: 500px; background-color: pink">Keep scrolling</div>
<div id="section3" style="height: 500px; background-color: Khaki">Almost there</div>

<p id="scroll-indicator">1</p>
```